# Analyze needed after a refresh materialized view?

Tags: postgresql, statistics, materialized-view

Are we supposed to run `ANALYZE myview;` on a PostgreSQL 9.6+ materialized view after running a `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY myview;`?

Or is it useless (maybe index statistics are already updated on refresh?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Table statistics are ***not*** updated automatically.

- They remain unchanged if refreshed with the `CONCURRENTLY` option.
- Without `CONCURRENTLY`, a new file is written for the table, and the basic counts `relpages` and `reltuples` in the system catalog `pg_class` are consequently reset to `0`. Table statistics (per column) in `pg_statistic` still remain unchanged, though.

I ran a quick test in Postgres 9.6 to confirm.

In some cases (where query plans don't depend on current statistics much) you may want to save the time and not run `ANALYZE` at all. In all other cases you'll want / need to schedule a manual `ANALYZE myview;` right after the `REFRESH`. Or you wait until autovacuum kicks in, which only happens if enough rows were changed (`CONCURRENTLY` actually runs DML commands on the MV to only affect changed rows.)

Comment: @poshest: Yes, thank you. Fixed.