# PostgreSQL 9.6 performance problem with Sum() aggregate query

Tags: postgresql, performance, aggregate, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-performance

I have the following table:

```
     id                | bigint                      | not null default nextval('shares_id_seq'::regclass)
     poolid            | text                        | not null
     blockheight       | bigint                      | not null
     networkdifficulty | double precision            | not null
     miner             | text                        | not null
     worker            | text                        |
     ipaddress         | text                        | not null
     created           | timestamp without time zone | not null
     useragent         | text                        |
     payoutinfo        | text                        |
     difficulty        | double precision            | not null default 0

Indexes:
        "shares_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
        "idx_shares_pool_block" btree (poolid, blockheight)
        "idx_shares_pool_created" btree (poolid, created)
        "idx_shares_pool_miner" btree (poolid, miner)
        "idx_shares_pool_miner_diff" btree (poolid, miner, difficulty)
```

I cannot wrap my head around why the following query takes so long:

```
explain analyze SELECT SUM(difficulty) FROM shares WHERE poolid = 'xmr1' AND miner = '4BCeEPhodgPMbPWFN1dPwhWXdRX8q4mhhdZdA1dtSMLTLCEYvAj9QXjXAfF7CugEbmfBhgkqHbdgK9b2wKA6nqRZQCgvCDm';
                                                                                QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=4150712.54..4150712.55 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=25490.101..25490.101 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on shares  (cost=389414.64..4143195.97 rows=3006629 width=8) (actual time=2499.409..24815.011 rows=7445802 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((poolid = 'xmr1'::text) AND (miner = '4BCeEPhodgPMbPWFN1dPwhWXdRX8q4mhhdZdA1dtSMLTLCEYvAj9QXjXAfF7CugEbmfBhgkqHbdgK9b2wKA6nqRZQCgvCDm'::text))
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 55232916
         Heap Blocks: exact=149273 lossy=2641988
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_shares_pool_miner  (cost=0.00..388662.98 rows=3006629 width=0) (actual time=2449.977..2449.977 rows=7445802 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((poolid = 'xmr1'::text) AND (miner = '4BCeEPhodgPMbPWFN1dPwhWXdRX8q4mhhdZdA1dtSMLTLCEYvAj9QXjXAfF7CugEbmfBhgkqHbdgK9b2wKA6nqRZQCgvCDm'::text))
 Planning time: 0.256 ms
 Execution time: 25490.137 ms
(9 rows)
```

I specifically created index *idx_shares_pool_miner_diff* for this scenario, yet it isn't even used. Can't PostgreSQL use the index due to MVCC?

**Update:**

Running `vacuum analyze shares` as suggested made PostgreSQL use the aforementioned index:

```
 Aggregate  (cost=546165.94..546165.95 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2489.446..2489.447 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using idx_shares_pool_miner_diff on shares  (cost=0.69..537874.79 rows=3316458 width=8) (actual time=0.041..1924.396 rows=7461785 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((poolid = 'xmr1'::text) AND (miner = '4BCeEPhodgPMbPWFN1dPwhWXdRX8q4mhhdZdA1dtSMLTLCEYvAj9QXjXAfF7CugEbmfBhgkqHbdgK9b2wKA6nqRZQCgvCDm'::text))
         Heap Fetches: 16575
 Planning time: 0.122 ms
 Execution time: 2489.477 ms
(6 rows)
```

I assume that's as fast as it gets without using parallel workers.

After reading the docs about index-only-scans, it looks like I'm taking a performance hit due to the constant heavy write activity on the shares table (> 200 inserts/sec), causing the many Heap-Fetches. Interestingly the number of Heap-Fetches is apparently only going up, never down.

Comment: Does this change if you do a `vacuum analyze shares`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. That made a difference. Updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your table is INSERT-only, there are ways to get your sums (much) faster.

Assuming there is a column with monotonically increasing values (like `id` or `created` in your example), create a [**`MATERIALZED VIEW`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) to pre-compute sums older than a (recent) given threshold. And then just add the sum of recent additions to it:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW shares_summed AS
SELECT poolid, miner, SUM(difficulty) AS sum_diff
FROM   shares
GROUP  BY  poolid, miner
ORDER  BY  poolid, miner;  -- optional, but to optimize some more
WHERE  created <  '2018-01-01 0:0';
```

If there are many combinations of `(poolid, miner)`, add a **`UNIQUE`** index on that. Also required to refresh `CONCURRENTLY`, see below.

Fetching a row from that table cost next to nothing. Then you only add recent additions to it:

```
SELECT sum(sum_diff) AS total_sum  -- takes care of possible missing rows
FROM  (
   SELECT sum_diff
   FROM   shares_summed
   WHERE  poolid = 'xmr1'
   AND    miner = '4BCeEPhod...'

   UNION ALL
   SELECT SUM(difficulty)
   FROM   shares
   WHERE  poolid = 'xmr1'
   AND    miner  = '4BCeEPhod...'
   AND    created >= '2018-01-01 0:0'
   ) sub;
```

You only have to adapt the threshold value from time to time and [`REFRESH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) the MV. Best with the **`CONCURRENTLY`** option, to ***avoid concurrency issues*** with your many `INSERT`s. Consider:

- [Analyze needed after a refresh materialized view?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194709/analyze-needed-after-a-refresh-materialized-view/194717#194717)

Remember the value and adapt queries accordingly. You might store it in another table.

To make it even faster, create a [partitioned table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-partitioning.html) and add another partition with pre-computed sums after every month (or whatever). You can easily schedule a monthly cron job to automate this. Then the threshold is always the start of the month or so:

```
SELECT sum(sum_diff) AS total_sum
FROM  (
   SELECT SUM(difficulty) AS sum_diff
   FROM   shares_summed_master  -- includes all partitions
   WHERE  poolid = 'xmr1'
   AND    miner = '4BCeEPhod...'

   UNION ALL
   SELECT SUM(difficulty)
   FROM   shares
   WHERE  poolid = 'xmr1'
   AND    miner  = '4BCeEPhod...'
   AND    created >= date_trunc('month', now())  -- careful, current time zone affects it
   ) sub;
```

Make sure there is no overlap, and pre-computed sums are current.

Table partitioning was largely improved and simplified with **Postgres 10**. Be sure to run the latest point release, some corner case bugs were fixed in Postgres 10.2. The above link to the manual is for version 9.6. [Current version here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

Comment: Tried both proposed solutions and then - out of curiosity - experimented with plain old triggers for insert and delete, which update corresponding rows in a pre-aggregation table which worked out nicely so far and is a bit easier to manage.